# How does a Customer model object know about the loadByEmail method of the model resource?

Tags: customer, model, resource-model

Consider the following code

```
$customer_email = "customer@example.com";
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail($customer_email);
```

When looking through Mage_Customer_Model_Customer I could not find a loadByEmail method anywhere in it's inheritance chain. Then I looked at it's resource model, Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer, and there it was.

My question is: how is it possible, that I load the model itself and get access to this method through the $customer_email variable?

Comment: I guess this question should be downvoted, so that noone gets tricked by it or closed or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed something. The method `loadByEmail` exists in the `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` class: 
For Magento 1.7.0.2 it starts at line 180 and looks like this:

```
public function loadByEmail($customerEmail)
{
    $this->_getResource()->loadByEmail($this, $customerEmail);
    return $this;
}
```

It's just a wrapper for `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer::loadByEmail` but it exists.

Comment: I feel so embarrassed. :D Thank you, you are right! I guess I should have used Ctrl + F.